# AngularJS simple Service

Tags: angularjs, service

I'm working on an AngularJS service. The first is getting a product's info from an API:

```
getProductInfo: function(ean) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    api.get('products/' + ean, {})
    .then(function(data) {
        service.currentProduct = data;
        deferred.resolve(data);
    }, function() {
        delete service.currentProduct;
        deferred.reject('Invalid EAN: ' + ean);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
},
```

For the second I want to take the EAN from product's info and use that as the variable to be placed in an external image link:

```
getProductImg: function() {
    var ean = ???
    var url = "http://externalurl" + ean + "_01c";
    return(url);
},
```

Ideally I would like to combine these so the external image is part of getProductInfo, is this possible?

Thanks,
Shanna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your service like that:

```
angular.module('core.products').service('Products', function($http, $q){    
    this.getInfo = function(ean){
        var defferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get('products/' + ean, {}).then(
            // success
            function(data) {
                var product = data;
                product.img = "http://externalurl" + ean + "_01c";                

                deferred.resolve(product);
            }, 
            // error
            function() {                
                deferred.reject('Invalid EAN: ' + ean);
            }
        );

        return deferred.promise;
    }
})
```

And use that service in controller:

```
angular.module('core.products').controller('ProductsController', function($scope, Products){

    $scope.getInfo = function(ean){
        Products.getInfo(ean).then(
            function(product){
                $scope.product = product;
            },
            function(error){
                alert(error);
            }
        )
    }

});
```

Comment: Very good thanks! It's just I need to use service.currentProduct = data; where you have var product = data;  Also on your deferred.resolve(product); did you mean to use product over data deferred.resolve(data); ?

Comment: If I want to access the image in the controller what would I need to do?

Comment: After resolving your promise you can access the image as prop of product. `$scope.product.image`